# Developing a simple reactive program with Haskell

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming

I am building a three-dimensional tic-tac-toe game. [I have already built the game itself that runs in command prompt](https://github.com/ryo0ka/tictactoe3d), and now I am building a system that runs the game on a cube of bi-color LED lamps and an input button.

As the input through the button and the output through the cube will happen simultaneously, this is going to be my first concurrent/reactive programming in functional languages. I am clueless at all. I have read and understood the basics of those programming concepts, but can't quite apply them to my problem.

- What kind of strategy and library is suit to this problem? (I don't know if this is a legitimate question..) I'm so lost that I need advice even about where to start from/with.
- (In the stragety/library above,) How can an even listener (or anything that reacts to certain events in the system) "update" data, how can such mutable data (which I expect are called rather like mutable reference because data themselves should be immutable) be used like, and how do you explain that it keeps the referential transparency (please ignore this question if nonsense)?
- (In the stragety/library above,) How does it deal with such a kind of input that the user can unintentionally input many times? For example, it's hard for us to "tap" a button at just one point of time. I want my program to recognize such sequential inputs as a single input.

Thank you so much for reading my weird English, and I would appreciate a lot if you could give me any pieces of guide or information. Thank you again!

Comment: do you have anything to interact with your *cube* (some C API, ...) - I think this will be the first step - after this I would start fleshing out the FFI (just inside `IO`) and then you can start looking for FRP frameworks (I guess any will do) - anyway I find this really interesting and it's a bit sad that this will most likely not fit the SO format - maybe you should link this question to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell) or ask in the mailing list because I think this will cause more than one question :D

Comment: Hi @CarstenKönig, thank you for your reply and mentioning the first step :) I've already got that part done; by that I mean I'm actually developing on the hArduino library, which enables Haskell to control Arduino processors through the Standard Firmata interface, which does all the FFI thing for us. So I already have all the tools to implement physical functions and features only with Haskell source and runtime. But thank you for clarifying it! :) And about the reddit forum, yes I think you're right that it's gonna be a mess if I end up having more questions in SO. I'm posting one there!

Comment: ah ok - nice :D - then look for an FRP framework you want to start with (or just try the `hArduino` first) - I think [sodium](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sodium) might be a good start - but here is a longer list to [choose from](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_Reactive_Programming#Libraries)

Comment: btw: if you manage to combine `hArduino` with any FRP lib then you should consider open-sourcing this ;) - I would love to help but sadly I don't own any board :( (but I am still really interested in the basic stuff and if I find some time I might get me one and help you out if I can ^^)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Thank you a lot! I posted the topic on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/32sy1x/developing_3d_tictactoe_on_arduino_in_haskell/ I have done some stuff with hArduino already, so I'm familiar and comfortable with the library. :) I'm going with sodium as you recommend, because it looks fairly basic and standard, and that's what I want at the first time to get familiar with the concept. I really appreciate your interest and advice for me and this project! :)))